# Problemas con mi app web una vez subida al servidor

Tags: php, web, app

Intentaré ser claro, he desarrollado una app web multicliente, no se si llamarla así es correcto. El tema es que la app de la parte del usuario no encuentra los archivos de estilos, imágenes entre otros, etc. La estructura de la app consta de lo siguiente:

- Carpeta Admin.

  - ficheros.
  - css.
  - inc.
  - documentos.php admin
- Carpeta Usuario.

  - admin

    - ficheros. (symlink ficheros - carpeta admin.)
    - css (symlink css - carpeta admin.)
    - inc (symlink inc - carpeta admin.)
    - documentos.php admin(Estos son independientes, no hay symlink)
  - css.
  - inc.
  - documentos.php usuario(Estos son independientes, no hay symlink)
- Carpeta Cliente.

  - admin. (symlink admin - carpeta usuario)
  - local.
  - documentos.php usuario (symlink carpeta usuario)

El problema surge como decía que una vez subidas al servidor, no encuentra los archivos relacionados con rutas relativas como lo hacía en el servidor local, de primeras he intentado hacer lo siguiente al inicio de los documentos para que obtuviera las rutas relativas:

Pero no se si esto es correcto, lo estoy haciendo mal o le falta algo por que no obtengo ningun resultado. Muchas gracias, por vuestra atención a mi mensaje y si alguien puede decirme algo o aportarme una solución sería genial. Un saludo.

Comment: configuraste tu apache para que tenga php?

Comment: Cuando dices _la app de la parte del usuario no encuentra los archivos_ ¿Son relativos a que? ¿Has comprobado que el archivo está disponible? ¿has comprobado que la salida html apunta al archivo en concreto? Ejemplo: `/usuario/css/estilo.css` ¿Has abierto el archivo en el navegador para comprobar que el enlace es correcto? ¿Estás usando `base href`? ¿Has comprobado que los enlaces simbólicos son seguidos en el servidor? Hay que hacer algunas pruebas previas para descartar y acotar aún más el problema. Una muestra de como se están enlazando o como se generan esos enlaces vendría bien.